# Does power bi have capability to have a dataset or report that connects to 2 datasets?

Tags: powerbi

I am exploring the following:

I have a power bi report with data model in the same file.

I can separate the report into one file and dataset into another file, and have a live connection from report to dataset.

Recently a new feature is introduced wherein I can create a  dataset (D2) which can make live connection to another dataset (D1), and the connection gets converted from live into DQ connection, and then in this dataset (D2) I can add new data sources to improve my model. Reports can connect using live connection to any dataset (D1 or D2).

Does power bi have capability to have a dataset or report that connects to 2 datasets?

Answer (score 1):

A report can only connect to **one dataset**, but **multiple dataflows**.
However, maybe
[Use composite models in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-composite-models) can solve your problem.

Comment: Does your answer consider this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-directquery-datasets-azure-analysis-services

Comment: Exactly. That page also refers to the **Composite Models** link I mentioned above.

Comment: [DirectQuery for Power BI datasets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-directquery-datasets-azure-analysis-services) is still in preview and must be explicitly enabled. It will allow you to connect to multiple datasets.